# Poor performance with sql server on azure vm when I write a lot of data to disk

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I need to move an existing application to windows azure VMs. This application write a lot of data (insert into) to DB.

So, I created a SQL Server machine on Azure VM, and configured the environment according the Microsoft best practice for SQL Server on azure VM (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn133149.aspx).

I tested this SQL query on my computer and on my SQL Server on azure VM:

```
WHILE @i <= 100000 BEGIN
INSERT INTO sales (id, created) VALUES (@i, GETDATE());
SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

When I run this query on my machine, its finished after 43 seconds.
When I run this query on the azure VM its take over 10 minutes!!! (I try this with single disk and striped with 2 and 4 disks).

I try to test more scenario code, with transaction:

```
WHILE @i <= 100000 BEGIN

-- Start a transaction
IF @i % 10000 = 1 
   BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 INSERT INTO sales (id) VALUES (@i);
 SET @i = @i + 1;

-- Commit after each 10,000 row
IF @i % 10000 = 0
  COMMIT;
END
```

this scenario works OK on both environments (my pc & azure VM).

When I ran SQLIO on the sql azure VM server, I got results that fit to the second query results (with transaction).

My application must run without transactions.

Anybody know how to resolve that?
Thank you.

Comment: If you're just comparing speeds of physical hardware to VM's, this question doesn't fit at StackOverflow. Perhaps ServerFault might be better? In any case, in its current form, you didn't even include machine sizing, either for your own machine or your deployed VM. Even if you posted this to ServerFault, it's unanswerable as it stands.

Comment: And what about the disks the log is stored on? By trying to write one line at a time inside a single transaction, you create a huge pressure on the log. Anyway, if you want to write such data to the database, there are better ways, like doing a single INSERT/SELECT to pull data from the source in one go. Perhaps, if you post the *actual* query, we could help you to fix it

Answer (score 1):

100.000 inserts one by one will be slow, because of the many inserts within the same transaction. Try this instead. It only has 1 insert:

```
;WITH d as
(
  SELECT rn
  FROM (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(0)) x(rn)
), numbers as
(
  SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn
  FROM d d1,d d2,d d3,d d4,d d5
)
INSERT sales (id, created)
SELECT 
  rn,
  getdate()
FROM
  numbers
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't change the simple query, because that in fact, the application that I moved to azure talking with MSSQL throw Dynamic CRM API, and its working with my first query scenario. I don't understand why in my machine I got result after 40 seconds and Azure VM over 10 minutes.

Comment: well if you want to optimize your script, you need to rewrite it, it is not well written.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - I don't think this has anything to do with the question (which doesn't belong on SO anyway) - the OP is comparing a physical machine to an Azure VM, neither of which are spec'd in the question, and asking why there's a perf difference. The contents of the script are irrelevant, and the question as it currently stands is unanswerable.

Comment: @DavidMakogon actually, this may be a valid question - a bad query behaves ... badly on the production server but works on the development server. How do you fix the bad query ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The OP has not given any information about the environment. If the local server has high CPU/attached disk specs, and the VM is A4 or smaller (meaning gen 1 cpu), it's a rather meaningless discussion. So no, as it stands, the question is not valid. Now: if the question is about *query optimization* then yes, it's a fine question, but it needs to be re-asked without any mention of server-vs-vm comparison.

Comment: Further comments received, several clarifications:  I try this on two azure VMs: A4 & a6, the data disks was configured according the Microsoft best practices (Sys DB disk, TempDb disk, User DB Disk, Tran Log Disk...) and each user DB & log  disks are striped from 3 disks.

Comment: @aviad_f - You really need to edit your question, and not bury more details in a comment to an answer.